# jQuery date picker not working in content pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am using a jQuery date picker. It works fine on a normal aspx page. But it doesn't work on the content pages.

This is the code in my content page

```
<asp:Content ID="body"  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
   <div  id="content">
    <div id="examples">
    <div>
        Default time picker :
        <input type="text" style="width: 70px;" id="timepicker.[1]" value="" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#timepicker\\.\\[1\\]').timepicker();
            });
        </script>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

I am not very familiar with jQuery but I suppose these lines cause problem since they check for the body tag. I tried using placing div id there but can't get it to work.

```
find("body").append($.timepicker.tpDiv);
$("body").append(this.tpDiv);
```

How can I append the div without body tag

Comment: I guess your first step is to check that the <script> tag that you are using, is the correct one to be loaded in the inner pages. we see on many different occasions that the code to include the jQuery file was not the correct way to do so.
post your script part from your master file or ViewStart code, so we can investigate it better.

Comment: Can you please post some more code? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here? By the looks of it you are trying to create the element at the same level as you called the timepicker...

Comment: to sum it up, check that any jQuery code else this malfunctioning one in your question is working and let us know.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed the same code works fine on normal aspx pages without masterpage.http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js this link contains the whole code

Comment: @Karthi: I meant something else, inside one of the inner pages that you have problem with DatePicker, do you have any other jQuery code that works?
if so, post the code that you are including your jQuery code with.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed no the page has no other jQuery code

Comment: @Karthi: ok, write down any jQuery code just to make sure that the library is loaded inside the page, and and let me know what happen.
also PLEASE, post more of your code, we need to help you, but you are not helping us :)

Answer (score 0):

May be u can use some other container ?? like

```
$("#anyDIV").append()
```

Comment: tried but never works   http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js this is the java script of the control

Answer (score 0):

use class selector.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 70px;" id="timepicker.[1]" value="" class="timepicker" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.timepicker').timepicker();
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.run your page.
2.right click --> inspectelement -->  copy id. 
3.now paste that id in your code and run.